# NetBeans debugging variable values

Tags: variables, netbeans

I am debugging in NetBeans IDE, where can I see assigned variables and their values?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

While you're in the debugger go `Window -> Debugger -> Variables`

Comment: you gotta run the debugger xD

Comment: Is there a way to see the return value of a method, assuming it's not assigned to a variable.

Answer (score 8):

You can also use <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> to bring up variable viewer.

Answer (score 4):

Generally, the pane underneath the code has some tabs - and one of them will say 'Variables'.  Click on that tab and you will see variables and their values.  You need to be actually running a debug session before the variables tab is available.

For this to show all local variables you need to have the line:

xdebug.show_local_vars=1

in your xdebug.ini file.  Don't forget to restart Apache if you add that line.

If you are not seeing all local variables then you may have hit the problem where your version of the module file (xdebug.so) has a bug.  This is the case currently for Ubuntu 10.04.

To fix this you need to compile a newer version of the xdebug.so file.  Follow the instructions at http://xdebug.org/wizard.php to get your new file which should replace your current xdebug.so file.

Comment: My netbeans showing GLOBAL variables but not my local variables

Answer (score 3):

There exists another solution that is

1. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd> to display `Evaluate Expression` Panel/Tab
2. Enter variable name in `Evaluate Expression` Panel/Tab
3. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> (or arrow icon at right of `Evaluate Expression` Panel/Tab

The variable's value is then displayed in `Variables` Panel just below (on my PC) `Evaluate Expression` Panel/Tab.

You can also use this solution to display EXPRESSION and not only VARIABLE !

Example: (String sSheetData is a String variable that contains a very big string)

```
sSheetData.substring(4000,4200);
StringTools.Right(sSheetData,100);
StringTools.Mid(sSheetData,4000,200);
```

This is also possible using `New Watch` callable using contextual menu.

But this is not as easy as using `Immediate Windows`  on Microsoft Visual Studio :-)